# Laravel/Lumen Sentinel setup

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, sentinel

How can I set up a Sentinel on Lumen? At first, I got

> Class 'Sentinel' not found

then I registered Sentinel and created an alias as follows:

```
$app->register(Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider::class);
class_alias(Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel::class, 'Sentinel');
```

but I got

> Class session.store does not exist

then I also registered session like so:

```
$app->register(Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class);
class_alias(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class, 'Session');
```

then I got:

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projects/gexd/zeno-new/mobile/vendor/illuminate/support/Manager.php on line 88 and defined.

Comment: why do you do this `class_alias` if you already use a good framework?

Comment: did you try to add it into composer? `composer require cartalyst/sentinel "2.0.*"` ? https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#installation

Answer (score 0):

After running `composer require cartalyst/sentinel "2.0.*"`, register it in `config/app.php`.

In providers use:

`Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider::class,`

And in alias section use :

`'Activation' => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Activation::class,
'Reminder'   => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Reminder::class,
'Sentinel'   => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel::class,`

You can see more [sentinel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0) . If covered these steps. Then maybe you forgot to use `use Sentinel;` at the top of your controller.